# Is the homogenization of an ideal actually an homogeneous ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

$R$ is a commutative and unitary ring. Let $R:=K[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ and $^{h}R:=K[Y_{0},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}]$ denote the multivariable polynomial rings in $n$ and $n+1$ variables, respectively. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal of $R$. Then, we define the homogenization of $\mathfrak{a}$ as the generated ideal in $^{h} R$ by the homogenization of the polynomials in $\mathfrak{a}$, i.e,
$$
{}^{h}{\mathfrak{a}}:=\left(\{{}^{h}f: f\in\mathfrak{a}\}\right).
$$
I have to add also the following definition: if $F\in R$, we define the homogenization of $F$ (which is an homogeneous polynomial) as:
$$
  ^{h}F(Y_{0},...,Y_{n}):=Y_{0}^{deg(F)}F\left(\frac{Y_{1}}{Y_{0}},...,\frac{Y_{n}}{Y_{0}}\right). 
 $$
My question is about the definition of ${}^{h}\mathfrak{a}$: **Why is ${}^{h}\mathfrak{a}$ an homogeneous ideal?** My definition of homogeneous ideal is the following: $\mathfrak{b}$ (ideal of $^{h}R$) is homogeneous if every element of $\mathfrak{b}$ could be expressed as a sum of a finite number of homogeneous polynomials (the different monomials that conform the polynomial), or equivalently, if it is generated by a finite number of homogeneous polynomials...

My attempt is: if I take $f\in {}^{h}\mathfrak{a}$, all I know is that $f=g_{1}{}^{h}f_{1}+\dots + g_{s}{}^{h}f_{s}$, where $f_{1},\dots,f_{s}\in \mathfrak{a}$ and $g_{1},\dots,g_{s}\in {}^{h}R$... But this is not a sum of homogeneous polynomials... and I don't see how ${}^{h}\mathfrak{a}$ can be expressed as an ideal generated by a finite number of homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Suppose $I$ is generated by a set $F$. Then there is a *finite* subset $S\subseteq F$ such that $I$ is generated by $S$.

Comment: Ok, thanks both... I am seeing the point... Thanks for the clarification! In my particular case, I am seeing that $R$ is a field, so $R[X_{0},\dots,X_{n}]$ is a noetherian ring, and so we have the finite generation property...